# Android Studio - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Sometimes when I'm trying to run app on android studio 3.6.3 i get this error:

> F:\smsapp\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This error does not happen constantly, but I'm not sure what is the cause and how to fix this permanently. I looked up some solutions and tried a couple of them:

- ending OpenJDK platform binary process - doesn't work
- invalidate caches/restart - sometimes it does work but it takes quite a lot of time to close and load project
- build -> clean project - mostly doesn't work because file is open
- find process using resmon.exe - turns out its android studio, so when I end the studio closes.
- deleting file - doesn't work because file is in use somehow

Sometimes it just starts working, by the time I finished writing this post error disappeared, but I'm sure it will come back again.

Comment: have you delete .gradle, .idea, build and also build folder inside app? 
then import it again.